# C# Xamarin.Forms Ошибка миграции EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, xamarin, миграция

Создал проект Xamarin.Forms и попытался подключить EF с миграцией. Мои действия:

1. Создал проект "Библиотека классов" .NET Standard и подключил библиотеки EF Core.
2. Написал туда следующий код:

```
 class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext, IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employee> Workers { get; set; }

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
        public ApplicationDbContext()
        {

        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder
              .Entity<Employee>()
              .HasMany(e => e.EmployeeProjects)
              .WithOne(p => p.Employee);

            modelBuilder
              .Entity<Employee>()
              .HasMany(e => e.LeaderProjects)
              .WithOne(p => p.Leader);

            modelBuilder
             .Entity<Employee>()
             .HasMany(e => e.ExecutorProjects)
             .WithMany(p => p.Executor);
        }
        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Filename=");

            return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }

    }
```

3. Создал новый проект "Console .NET 5". Добавил зависимости, а именно "Библиотека классов".
4. В консольном менеджере пакетов пишу Add-migrations Initial
5. Если убрать интерфейс, то при попытке создать миграцию выдает ошибку "Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728"](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728%22)
   Реализовал интерфейс, но проблема в том, что строку подключения приходится хардкодить. Как сделать так, чтобы я мог объявить строку подключения из проекта Android и чтоб при этом успешно проходила миграция?
   Еще проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю какая строка подключения должна быть у Android

Comment: Строка подключения зависит не от андроида, а от того, [к какому серверу вы подключаетесь](https://www.connectionstrings.com/). Текущего конструктора вам вполне достаточно в классе, просто надо вызвать его при инициализации приложения, что-то типа `services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(x => x.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));`

Comment: Дело в том, что я использую локальную базу данных и мне нужно где-то ее расположить. services применимо только для ASP. NET с его инверсией зависимостей. В Xamarin такого нет

Comment: Текущего конструктора вам вполне достаточно в классе, просто надо вызвать его при инициализации приложения, что-то типа `services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(x => x.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));` И [ссылка, которую вам дали](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728) очень крутая и там действительно все способы описаны, например, я как-то по ней пробовал фабрику создавать, а остальные способы просто маст хэв.

Comment: Попробуйте строку подключения задавать в команде миграции, как [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/limitations#idempotent-script-limitations)

Comment: Нет, мне не нужно хардкодить строку. Я хочу эту строку получить, что-то типа Environment.Directory + dbName

Comment: Не надо ничего хардкодить. В процессе разработки вы знаете путь к тестовой БД - его и указывайте в командах миграции. А в процессе выполнения передавайте путь к рабочей БД в метод `CreateDbContext`.

Comment: Вот именно, что путь я не знаю, так как это ксамарин, то я предполагаю, что бд будет создаваться в папках моего приложения. В каких именно? Как мне правильно прописать путь?